# VBA-Open a specific file when the file name keeps changing with the date

Tags: excel, vba, file, automation, excel-2016

I have a macro in Excel 2016 that currently works to open a specific email template. That template requires a form added as an attachment. My current code can open the file's location, but then the user has to find/select the correct file.

How do I get VBA to open the required form instead of just the folder? I know the file name & path, but the file name keeps changing with the version. All of the threads I could find involved known file names and unknown path. This is a **known path** and **partially known file name** due to the periodical nature of the file.

Ex. Today is October, but the most recent version is *C:\filepath\Form_Sept_2021.pdf* with previous dated versions already moved to an archive folder.

```vb
Sub Open_Template()

Dim myolapp As Object
Dim myitem As Object
Dim answer As Integer

answer = MsgBox("Do you still need to create the required form?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Form Required")

Set myolapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
myolapp.Session.Logon

'This is the email that requires a form attached

Set myitem = myolapp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\\filepath\email.oft")
myitem.Display

'This part needs modified to open the pdf file from the above example

If answer = vbYes Then
    Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & "C:\\filepath\" vbNormalFocus)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need to attach the form to the mail?   You should be able to use `Dir("C:\filepath\Form*.pdf")` to find the matching form file name, where `*` is a variable part of the name.

Answer (score 0):

Im thinking you could use a variable in your file name as suggested above. You could assign the variable to be the month (“Mmmm”) and then plug it in. You could use an if statement to test for current month then try going back a month.

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like this:

```vb
Dim LastMonth   As Date
Dim Period      As String
Dim FileName    As String

' Other code.

If answer = vbYes Then
    LastMonth = DateAdd("m", -1, Date)
    Period = "Form_" & Left(Format(LastMonth, "mmmm"), 4) & Format(LastMonth, "_yyyy")
    FileName = "C:\\filepath\\" & Period & ".pdf"
    Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & FileName, vbNormalFocus)
End If
```

Not sure about the double backslashes.

Comment: Might work if I was looking for something with an exact date window. The dates are not specific. If the file is updated today, then the month is this month. If it hasn't been used in a while, it could be up to 90 days back for the valid one or older if it hasn't been used for a bit and requires updated first.

Comment: Well: "_Today is October, but the most recent version is C:\filepath\Form_Sept_2021.pdf_" is the info you provided. Adjust the code for other business rules.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you need to attach the form to the mail? You should be able to use Dir("C:\filepath\Form*.pdf") to find the matching form file name, where * is a variable part of the name. –
> Tim Williams

Since the file's date on the name can vary depending on how recently it was updated, I found that I can use the `Dir` command with wild card to help find the file in the directory per Tim's suggestion. Then I told excel to open that file.

```vb
Dim form As String

'Same code as before up through the If/Then statement

If answer = vbYes Then
  'Find the file name where it is the only pdf in the directory starting with "Form"
    form = Dir("C:\\filepath\Form*.pdf")
  'Use Excel to open the file in the appropriate program
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "C:\\filepath\" & form
End If
```

Although, I could also specify the program to open the file in using `Call Shell("program.exe" "C:\filepath\" & form)` where *program.exe* is *AcroRd32.exe* for Adobe or any other chosen *exe* viewing the file.